# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pencolor'

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, attributeerror, nonetype

**Hi everyone.**

It's my first time here and I'm new in the Python.

When I wrote this code

```
import turtle
t=turtle.Pen()
t=turtle.bgcolor("black")
sides=6
colors=("blue", "red", "green", "white", "yellow", "purple")
for x in range(360):
t.pencolor(colors[x % sides])
t.forward(x*3/sides+x)
t.left(360/sides+1)
t.width(x*sides/200)
```

and ran it, I received a message:

> "Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/emin_/PycharmProjects/firstproject/AydA.py", line 10, in 
>    t.pencolor(colors[x % sides]) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pencolor'".

I will be very thankful for any advice and help.

*Sincerely, paDrEdadash*

Comment: `t=turtle.bgcolor("black")` You're reassigning `t` to a function call that has a null return value.  And I believe `bgcolor()` is a screen function, not a turtle pen function.

Comment: @JohnGordon, `bgcolor()` is a screen *method* but also exposed as a top level *function* of the turtle module so `turtle.bgcolor("black")` is correct. Just the assignment of the worthless return value is bogus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with the assignment of `None` in `t=turtle.bgcolor("black")` that @JohnGordon points out (although `turtle.bgcolor("black")` is fine), your indentation as shown is incorrect and the code has the potential to error with an `index out of range` on `colors` if `sides` and the `len(colors)` don't coincidentally match.  I recommend an approach like the following to avoid problems:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

SIDES = 6

COLORS = ("blue", "red", "green", "white", "yellow", "purple")

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("black")

turtle = Turtle()

for x in range(360):
    turtle.pencolor(COLORS[(x % SIDES) % len(COLORS)])
    turtle.forward(x*3 / SIDES + x)
    turtle.left(360 / SIDES+1)
    turtle.width(x * SIDES/200)

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @cdlane, 
Thanks for your recommendation. I'll try it.